# PHP Dynamic form( $_POST)

Tags: php, html, forms, post, dynamic

so.. I'm facing a problem with dynamic form/`$_POST`... I need to echo the image i selected via radio button in the `if(isset($_POST['Submit_bc3']))`... But it's not working, I don't get it.. How can i make this problem go away? Code:

```
<?php
    $image_url = $user['image_location'];
    $directory2 = "../../../login_/assets/playercards/";
    $images2 = glob($directory2 . "*.jpg");
    if (isset($_POST['Submit_bc3'])) {
       echo $image2;
    }else{
       foreach($images2 as $image2)
    {
    echo '<img src="'.$image2.'" border="0" height="81px" width="156px" />';
    echo "<input type='Radio' name='".$image2."' value=''></input>";
    }
    }
?>



<button type="submit" class="button" name="Submit_bc3" data-bind="vortexExternalLinkAction: ''">_LETS_GO</button>
```

Comment: Where do you set the first `$image2`?

Comment: Your radio buttons don't make sense, each of them has a different name. All the buttons in a radio button group have to have the same name. The differences should be in the value.

Comment: You should give as @Barmar said, a unique name to every radio and in the value attribute you set the image name, so you can get it when you submit.

Comment: Aye, but I don't know how excatly to get away without radio button...

Answer (score 1):

`$image2` doesn't exist in the code before you echo it after checking whether the variable in POST `isset`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how could I change it? A little snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give all the buttons the same name so they'll be a single radio button group. Then you use that name in `$_POST` to get the value after submission.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit_bc3'])) {
    echo $_POST['image2'];
}else{
    foreach($images2 as $image2)
        {
            echo '<img src="'.$image2.'" border="0" height="81px" width="156px" />';
            echo "<input type='Radio' name='image2' value='".htmlentities($image2)."'></input>";
        }
}
```